# POI Spreadsheet Localisation

Tags: java, localization, apache-poi

Using Apache POI OOXML and XSSF mode, creating a new workbook, how does one set the spreadsheet's language (i.e. English (United States))? I can't find anything on it. The setting does not need to be cell-specific and should apply to all sheets. I am using POI version 4.1.0.

Comment: The storage of the sheets data in `Excel` files is not localized. The storage of the sheets data is always English US in terms of function names, list delimiters  and decimal and thousands delimiters.  Only the `Excel` applications are localized. The `Excel` GUI reads the data from the file and does translation of function names, list delimiters  and decimal and thousands delimiters. then.

Comment: @AxelRichter I would accept that as an anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage of the sheets data in `Excel` files is not localized. The storage of the sheets data is always English US in terms of function names, list delimiters and decimal and thousands delimiters. Only the Excel applications are localized. The `Excel GUI` reads the data from the file and does translation of function names, list delimiters and decimal and thousands delimiters then.

Let's have an example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class CreateExcel {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
    new Object[] {"Value", "Date", "Formatted value", "Formula"},
    new Object[] {123.456789, new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 15), 123.456789, "ROUND(A2,2)"},
    new Object[] {1234.56789, new GregorianCalendar(2019, 5, 15), 1234.56789, "ROUND(A3,2)"}
   };

   DataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
   CellStyle dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   dateStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("DDDD, MMMM, DD, YYYY"));
   CellStyle numberStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   numberStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00 \" Coins\""));

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
     Cell cell = row.createCell(c);

     if (r == 0) cell.setCellValue((String)data[r][c]);
     if (r > 0 && c == 0) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)data[r][c]);
     } else if (r > 0 && c == 1) {
      cell.setCellValue((GregorianCalendar)data[r][c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
     } else if (r > 0 && c == 2) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)data[r][c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(numberStyle);
     } else if (r > 0 && c == 3) {
      cell.setCellFormula((String)data[r][c]);
     }
    }
   }

   for (int c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(c);
   }

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

As you see nothing in the code is localized. All is `en_US`. Function name is `ROUND` in the formula, delimiter between function parameters is comma, same would be list delimiter, and decimal delimiter in double values is dot. Also the number format codes are `en_US`.

No content stored in the `Excel.xlsx` file is localized in any way.

But If I am opening the `Excel.xlsx` in my German `Excel`, then it looks like:

[image]

Note the formula `=RUNDEN(A3;2)`. Function name is translated to German, delimiter between function parameters is semicolon, same would be list delimiter, and decimal delimiter in double values is comma, thousands separator is dot.

Also the number format codes are German now:

[image]

Why is this? Mainly because it is a German `Excel` application. But also because of the `Windows` regional settings which are determining the date formats

[image]

...and decimal delimiter, list delimiter and thousands separator.

[image]